# How to capture error message text in appium

Tags: java, appium

[image: Screenshot of error message]

[image: UI Automator Capture]

Error message is against EditText field. We don't have any direct locator available which points to error message. Can anyone suggest what alternate we have to handle this in appium.

Comment: Have you tried taking a snapshot with UIAutomator while the error message is displayed?

Comment: Yes I tried that we don't have any locator for error message. Updated with UIAutomator screen

Comment: Please add a screenshot to your original post with the message highlighted showing the properties, and preferably also another one with the image (!) selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method if you are not able to assert Error message against EditText field.

1. Trigger text message on the screen
2. Capture screenshots
3. Convert image to text file

   ```
   def assettoast(string)
    sname = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
    $driver.driver.save_screenshot("#{sname}")

    #Make sure tesseract is installed in the system. If not you can install using "brew install tesseract" in mac
    system ("tesseract #{sname} #{sname}")

    text_file="#{sname}.txt"
    var= get_string_from_file(string, text_file)
    raise if var != true
   end
   ```
4. Check whether error message is there in text file

   ```
   def get_string_from_file(word, filename)
    File.readlines(filename).each do |line|
    return true if line.include?(word)
    end
   end
   ```

Comment: This method can exactly match the text. However you may have to convert this to python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solved my problem. Guys who want solution in java can visit : http://chillyfacts.com/simple-java-program-code-convert-image-text/

Answer (score 0):

There is no you will get using uiautomatorviewer and Google's original UiAutomator. Check old [thread](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2641)

However you may try Appium own implementation UiAutomator2 and [Appium desktop inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop), maybe it will parse error.

Otherwise there is new appium end-point to compare images:

```
/session/:sessionId/appium/compare_images
```

You can use it to verify the error on screen